# Why shouldn't I use Array Literals with Contains to avoid Multiple Ors in a Boolean check?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I've started using Arrays Literals with [IList.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.contains%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as an alternative to multiple Ors. Are there good reasons I shouldn't?

Example VB.Net code:

```
Dim foo = "d"
Dim bar = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"}.Contains(foo)
```

versus

```
Dim foo = "d"
Dim bar = foo = "a" Or foo = "b" Or foo = "c" Or foo = "d" _
          Or foo = "e" Or foo = "f" Or foo = "g" Or foo = "h"
```

After some further experimentation I could also do this, which I don't intend to do:

```
Dim bar = Array.IndexOf({"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"}, foo) <> -1
```

Note that I'm only using Strings in this example, but the method applies to any value type.

Are there reasons other than speed that should make me favor the 2nd option over the 1st?

Edit for future visitors: To summarize the answer in the comments. No. Use whichever method you prefer.

Comment: I must be searching the wrong way. I couldn't find a duplicate to this or even anyone talking about it on the internet. :-/

Comment: a `HashSet<string>` might be faster.

Comment: Does "array literal" mean an initializer? Surely you can imagine the first option is a lot cleaner..

Comment: This is just the same as using & to join strings in VB.net... in short the problem MUCH BIGGER if you need performance optimizations like that

Comment: @JeroenVannevel By array literal, I mean what I posted. Things like `{1,2,3,4}` that doesn't require creating a variable and can be used inline.

Comment: @DanielA.White Well, yes obviously, but that complicates things. Are you suggesting I create the Hashset just for the single check and use it there?

Comment: @DanielCook: yeah, apparently that's a VB.NET thing. It stays the same though: use a collection; don't separate them into multiple statements. It's a lot easier to read and maintain and there is no performance difference unless you sacrifice gigantic amounts of maintainability.

Comment: @Jay I don't follow. How is this the same? How is it even related? I'm not really worried about micro-optimization. I was just trying to assure there were no major gotchas I'm unaware of here. Perhaps this is a bad question...

Comment: @JeroenVannevel If you're suggesting I do something different, please elaborate in an answer so I can upvote you. Right now, I don't really get what you're saying.

Comment: @DanielCook: I'm entirely with Dasblinkenlight here: just use the `.Contains()` method as shown in your first example. The only times I would consider the second option is when there are guaranteed < 5 elements to perform the check on.

Comment: @All Thanks. I guess my real question was apparently whether or not this was primarily opinion based (meaning it doesn't make much difference). Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good reason to choose `Array.IndexOf ... <> -1` over `Contains`: both have the same speed, but `Contains` explains the intention better, because you do not need to look for the `... <> -1` part.

A solution with an `OR` is a linear search, too, so there will be no noticeable difference in speed. Once you get past few items, though, the readability starts to suffer, because the same variable is repeated over and over in multiple pieces of code that look similar to each other.

A solution that could give you additional speed is `HashSet of String`, because the search in a hash-based container goes faster. However, you should consider this alternative only if you can build the hash set upfront, and then reuse it in multiple checks. If you build a hash set on the spot only to make a check, you do not gain in speed, because construction of the hash set takes linear time.